# Gnome Seahorse Crashing all the time

Tags: apparmor, seahorse

I have Ubuntu 22.04.2 on my Latitude 5490.

Very often I have a small window opening saying "The application Passwords and Keys has closed unexpectedly", mostly right after I boot my computer.

Most times I click "Send report" but since the problem has been repeating for a long time I am trying to get a deeper look.

Here is the crash report (minus the core dump): https://pastebin.com/tpTsiT20

One thing that caught my attention in the crash report is:

```
UnreportableReason:
 You have some obsolete package versions installed. Please upgrade the following packages and check if the problem still occurs:
 
 libapparmor1
```

If I do `apt show libapparmor1` I see `Version: 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.2` which is the latest version for Ubuntu jammy: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/libapparmor1. AppArmor 3.0.4 is not even that old: https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/-/tags/v3.0.4

Any idea what I could try, and is there anything i should do about this `libapparmor1` thing?

Comment: Exact same issue here on 22.04 with on ThinkPad T540p. Happened only once for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue stopped happening after I updated to Ubuntu 22.11, so I guess my Ubuntu installation did have an obsolete version of `libapparmor1` for some reason.